# Javafx image from download link

Tags: java, javafx

I am uploading images to my backend and producing download links I want to download the image and display it in javafx I found this solution:

```
    ImageView imageView = ImageViewBuilder.create()
            .image(new Image(imageSource))
            .build();
```

But I am using JavaFx 11 and it seems there is no such thing as ImageViewBuilder in my javafx scene imageView package? Any ideas or an alternative way to do it?

Comment: The builders have been deprecated for a while. You should just use the constructors of `ImageView` and `Image`.

Comment: @Slaw I thought that ImageViewBuilder downloads the file first and then creates an image with it. So is using BufferedInputStream(new URL('http:/image.png').openStream()); the right way to download the file first before creating the image?

Comment: Note that `ImageViewBuilder` simply creates an `ImageView` using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). You can do effectively the same thing using the constructors (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builder classes were deprecated a while ago. For more information see [JDK-8124188](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8124188), [JDK-8092861](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092861), and [this mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html). That said, the `Image` class can still load remote images but you should use the constructors instead of the builders.

From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) (**emphasis** mine):

> The `Image` class represents graphical images and is used for loading images from a specified `URL`.
>
> Supported image formats are:
>
> - BMP
> - GIF
> - JPEG
> - PNG
>
> Images can be resized as they are loaded (for example to reduce the amount of memory consumed by the image). The application can specify the quality of filtering used when scaling, and whether or not to preserve the original image's aspect ratio.
>
> **All URLs supported by [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html) can be passed to the constructor.** If the passed string is not a valid `URL`, but a path instead, the `Image` is searched on the classpath in that case.
>
> Use [`ImageView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) for displaying images loaded with this class. The same `Image` instance can be displayed by multiple `ImageView`s.

So you can use:

```
String remoteUrl = ...;
Image image = new Image(remoteUrl);
ImageView view = new ImageView(image);

// or...
ImageView view = new ImageView(remoteUrl);
```

The second option takes advantage of the `ImageView(String)` constructor. Note that it precludes you from loading the image in the background (without custom code), which the constructors of `Image` provide an option for. If you want to control your own `InputStream` you can do that as well using the appropriate constructor of `Image`; don't forget to close the `InputStream` in this case.